# How to use INotifyPropertyChanged with Validation on WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having a little trouble trying to use INotifyPropertyChanged with Validation in WPF. Basically, I want the TextBox warning the user about the empty field and updating (with Binding) the value in the code behind the XAML.

Almost everything is working just fine, the only problem is when, for example, I type in the TextBox the string "Hello World" and then erase everything. The code in the back doesn't update on the last character deleted and instead of having a null or empty string, he keeps the value "H".

My short code is as follows:

UserControlClientes.xaml

```
<TextBox x:Name="NomeTextBox" CharacterCasing="Upper" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Nome" TargetNullValue="''" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <domain1:RequiredField ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

(the 'domain1' is defined and references the folder where is the RequiredField.cs)

UserControlClientes.xaml.cs

```
public class Dados_Administrativos: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _Nome;

    public string Nome
    {
        get { return _Nome; }
        set
        {
            _Nome = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Nome"));
            }
        }
    }
}


public UserControlClientes()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Cliente ClienteBind = new Cliente();
    DataContext = ClienteBind;
}
```

RequiredField.cs

```
    public class RequiredField: ValidationRule
    {
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((value ?? "").ToString())
                ? new ValidationResult(false, "Required field")
                : ValidationResult.ValidResult;
        }
    }
```

I'm new to WPF, so am I doing this in the right way? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: As a general note, a UserControl should never have its own, private view model in its DataContext. Such a private view model would not be accessible from outside the control and could hence not be part of an application-wide view model structure. Just don't explicitly set the control's DataContext, and instead pass an "external" view model  object, e.g. by `<local:UserControlClientes DataContext="{Binding ClientsViewModel}"/>`. Or by similarly binding the Content of a ContentControl which has the control in its ContentTemplate.

Comment: What is your expectation towards this behavior? How should it behave? Your validation rule ensures that the text is not empty, so of course when you delete each character one-by-one, the last one remaining before the box is empty is still valid. After that the box is empty and the validation rule fails, so the soure is not updated. From the behavior that you show it is working as expected.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for the tip, I will do that.

Comment: @thatguy I was expecting that the source will be updated (with empty) even when the validation rules fails. But, with what you're saying, I guess that's is not the way validation works, right? Is there anyway I can verify if the textbox is empty (from the main code)?

Comment: @Clemens I'm having problems doing what you said. I only need to declare the DataContext on the parent (a Window, in my case) and the child (UserControl) will receive the same DataContext? How is the proper way to declare the datacontext, in the xaml or in the constructor?

Comment: Any element in the Window's XAML will *inherit* the value of the Window's DataContext. Whether you set it in XAML or in code behind doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You may change the behaviour of your ValidationRule, so that it first updates the source property before running the validation, by setting its [`ValidationStep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.validationstep) property to `UpdatedValue`

```
<local:RequiredField
     ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"
     ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"/>
```

---

Besides that, I'd also suggest to remove the UserControl's dependency on a specific view model by exposing one or more bindable properties, like e.g. a `ClientName` property. In the example below, the property is registered such that it binds two-way by default.

```
public partial class ClientControl : UserControl
{
    public ClientControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string ClientName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ClientNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ClientNameProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ClientNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ClientName), typeof(string), typeof(ClientControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
}
```

The elements in the control's XAML would bind to its own properties by means of `RelativeSource` Bindings:

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourNamespace.ClientControl" ...>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Margin="10">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="ClientName"
                         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}"
                         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:RequiredField
                            ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"
                            ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"/>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In the MainWindow (or wherever you use the control), you would bind its properties to the properties of an arbitrary view model:

```
<local:ClientControl ClientName="{Binding NamePropertyInViewModel}"/>
```

---

The ValidationRule could also be improved a bit:

```
public class RequiredField : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value as string) // here
            ? new ValidationResult(false, "Required field")
            : ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```